# How do I remove ' ï»¿' from a string in PHP?

Tags: php

This character is coming from the database. I have a description which contains the image tag and text, but `ï»¿` is appearing in the beginning of that description.

Comment: Is that value actually **in** the database or is it being appended somewhere else?

Comment: Use string replace `str_replace();`

Comment: It might be an issue with character encoding. Are you using UTF-8?

Comment: ï»¿ is the [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) as represented in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: if your doing any cleaning of the string anywhere and are using any foreign language characters or weird stuff, you need to use the mb string functions to keep them intact.  so mb_str_replace()... and so on and so forth.  There pretty much a mb_ prefixed version of most regular string manipulation functions.

Comment: I have changed file encoding to UTF-8 without BOM, but no success str_replace also did not work with BOM. I will check with mb_str_replace and post if it works. thanks all for replying